# Lost ODBC connection #Name? error in a form bound to a linked table

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc, azure-sql-database, adodb

I have a form which is bound to an Azure SQL table. From time to time our corporate VPN cuts off and the ODBC connection is lost. There are no error messages but the form's data disappears and all of the textboxes show the #Name? error.

Is there any way to detect a lost connection or run a code when textboxes show an error?

I have been playing with the Form_Error event but it doesn't seem to fire in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a great way to trap and deal with ODBC errors. In most cases, a ODBC fail means you have to re-start Access.

However, the latest "native" driver is supposed to deal with this issue, and has built in abilities to re-connect when a connection is broken.

This means and suggests you want to use the latest ODBC driver. That is native 17. You can download it here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567

A few things:
You have to install this on each workstation. The older "legacy" driver was and is installed on all copies of windows by default. This goes all the way back to windows 98SE edition. So, most Access developers use this default driver (sql server driver).

And on your local office network (LAN), then this setup is rather fine. However, now that you have the "wild" internet between Access desktop, and the back end database? Well, then of course the probability of a dis-connect or even minor interruption is VERY high. The older drivers simply do not deal with this issue at all, or not at all well.

The newer native drivers for sql server are much better in this regards, and are designed with Azure in mind. So, give native 17 driver a try.

You will have to re-link your access tables using this new connection. I STRONG STRONG suggest that you use a FILE dsn when you do this, since then Access converts the DSN into a DSN-less connection. This will allow you to distribute the front end application to any workstation, and you not have to configure or setup a DSN on each work station. You will however have to ensure that the native driver is installed on each workstation, since as noted the newer native drivers are not installed by default. And they are not installed when you install access either.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer.

I already use ODBC 17 driver, with DSN-less connection strings defined in VB.

So if we ignore the ODBC timeout, are you aware of any form event that would fire when data from that form 'disappears' and is replaced with the #Name? value?

I have found a semi-workaround which requires the user to 'push the button' and get the data back, but I would like to run this code automatically. What seems to work is creating a new ADODB connection and then requerying the form, but again the process is manual